# How to attach agent without a jar?

Tags: java, jar, jvm, agent, byte-buddy

*(Using Java 11)*
I could inject agent at runtime with jar, via:

```java
VirtualMachine jvm = VirtualMachine.attach(jvmPid);
jvm.loadAgent("/path/to/agent.jar");
jvm.detach();
```

Is there any way to attach **without** a jar ?
I can do that With `byte-buddy`, but how to do it without 3rd party libraries like `byte-buddy` ?

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do this? It seems a little like an X-Y problem. In principle you could do what byte-buddy does yourself, which is essentially to define classes from a byte array. `sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass` can define classes from byte arrays, though accessing `sun.misc.Unsafe` type methods on java 11 is a little tricky.

Comment: @PiRocks A code challange need to do things like this, I can do that with a jar created by hand, but the challange need to do it without a jar.

Comment: Java Agent is a JAR file by [definition](https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk14/docs/api/java.instrument/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html). It's not clear what do you want to "attach" without a JAR file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have a jar file for this.

The Byte Buddy agent (*byte-buddy-agent*, not *byte-buddy* jar) contains the agent manifest header itself. In a first attempt, it tries to locate its own jar on the local file system (via `getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()`). If it cannot do this or exists as a non-jar file in a folder, it creates a temporary jar file with the required properties.

*byte-buddy-agent* is a minimal, zero-dependency jar. I'd recommend using it as namespaces for the attach API differ on old IBM and HotSpot VMs, it requires different setup on Java 9+ and since Byte Buddy can emulate attachment on non-JDK VMs if JNA is present. (Disclaimer: I am the author.)

Comment: Surely they could use a fully native agent, which wouldn't require a jar?

Comment: then it requires an so file.

Answer (score 0):

Create jar in temp file and then load it, java has all means for this.